# How to use FTD2xx library on QtCreator (with MSVC2012 compiler)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, ftdi

I have trouble in making an application which communicates FTDI devices via [D2xx driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm).There is some example project for Visual Studio in ftdi's website. But there isn't for QtCreator. I chose QtCreator as c++ IDE because my application needs Qt framework.
I put ftd2xx.h and ftd2xx.lib in the Qt project directory.

(ftd2xx.lib is static library, which were originally located  in [download-folder]\CDM v2.08.30 for Windows 8.1\Static\i386)

When sample source code was compiled, I got following error message.

Error message when I use .pro file(1).

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'ftd2xx.lib'
```

Error message when I use .pro file(2).

```
error: Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side.
```

How should I correct Qt project setup in order to utilizes ftd2xx library?

My source code and .pro file is here.

[main.cpp]

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
    FT_STATUS ftStatus;
    ftStatus =  FT_Open(0,&ftHandle);

    return a.exec();
}
```

[.pro file if the checkbox is enabled] ---(1)

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-02-11T18:51:08
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = D2XXtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += ftd2xx.h

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lftd2xx
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lftd2xxd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libftd2xx.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libftd2xxd.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/ftd2xx.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/ftd2xxd.lib
```

[.pro file if the checkbox is **NOT enabled**] ---(2)

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-02-11T18:51:08
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = D2XXtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += ftd2xx.h

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lftd2xx

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

win32:!win32-g++ PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/ftd2xx.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libftd2xx.a
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Note]

OS: Windows 8.1

IDE: Qt Creator 3.0.0

Compiler: MSVC2012(32bit)

Target device: ft232hl

**[Additional Note]**

The configuration of "Add Library" is following.
If I enable the checkbox "Add "d" suffix for debug version, then I got error message about LNK1104. Otherwise, I got different error message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that you've made a typo in your error message, and the real error message reads as follows:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'ftd2xxd.lib'
```

See that `d` there? It doesn't belong, there's no `ftd2xxd.lib`. You need to change any references to `ftd2xxd.lib` back to `ftd2xx.lib`, re-run qmake, and you should be all set. Otherwise your .pro file seems correct.

After your edit, you gave a .pro file with the "checkbox enabled". That's certainly not true, since the contents you show imply that the checkbox is *disabled*, **not** enabled.

Anyway, we don't care what the dialog box settings are. Just show the actual `.pro` file that you really use, because so far I don't know which one you do use, and I don't know if you've re-run qmake after the `.pro` file was changed.

Are you sure that the `ftd2xx.lib` file is actually in the same folder where the `.pro` file is?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't make a typo and error message is the same as I quoted before. I explain the reason why the file name become ftd2xxd by adding additional comment.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing comment.Let me correct what I wrote aditionally. Second .pro file is generated when the checkbox is disabled. I actually tried both .pro file. As I mentioned before, I got different error message respectivelly. I put ftd2xx.lib file into the directory which contains .pro file and source code (main.cpp, ftd2xx.h)

Comment: Let me apologize to you. Your hunch is right. After deleting build-xxxx folder, which is automatically generated by QtCreator, error message has changed as follows.(I use .pro file (1) in this time)                                     error:[ dependent'C:\Users\******\workspace\QtCreator_work\D2XXtest\ftd2xxd.lib' does not exist.] I think the checkbox "Add "d" suffix for debug version should be turned off. Is it right?

Comment: @yufit_in_Japan Yes, it should be turned off. Make sure that the .pro file looks correct (no ftd2xxd.lib references).